# Chart.js dynamically-created charts do not obey chart options

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm dynamically creating chart objects using this code inside a loop:

```
chartObjectArray.push(new Chart(chartContextArray[i]).Line(chartDataArray[i]), chartOptions);
```

The charts get drawn on the screen, but the chartOptions parameter is essentially ignored.  However, if I manually create the chart objects like this...

```
var myChart = new Chart(chartContextArray[0]).Line(data, chartOptions);
```

...then it works; options are obeyed when charts are drawn.  This chart object (myChart) when logged is much more fully fleshed-out than the object created from the loop.  Am I incorrectly building the chart objects in the loop?  Perhaps this is more of a javascript question.

Comment: are you able to post your full code to see what is happening? Or even better in a fiddle to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

If you have different chart options for each chart, you need to create a clone of the chartOptions object for each chart.

For plain JavaScript, I usually prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591639/360067 for its simplicity, but if you have libraries (jQuery, etc) you have a lot of other options.